# Why the summation is printed like this?

Tags: amsmath

The values of the upper and lower limits of a summation are usually printed below and above sigma. But I find TeX something very unusual. How to correct this?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
<\mu_{m}> = \frac{\sum_{-J}^{J}{-g\mu_{\beta}M_{J}B.\exp{\left(\frac{-g\mu_{\beta}M_{J}B}{kT}\right)}}}{\sum_{-J}^{J}{\exp{\left(\frac{-g\mu_{\beta}M_{J}B}{kT}\right)}}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Don't use `<>`. Use `\langle \rangle` instead.

Comment: It's because you have the sums in a fraction. Use `\sum\limits_{-J}^{J}` to change the limit position.

Comment: @Sigur `\langle \rangle`, makes it soooo thin

Comment: OK, but `<` is a relation symbol and `\langle` is a delimiter. They are different in some sense and the space around them are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX by default uses *scriptstyle* for sums inside fractions. You can change the sums to *displaystyle* like this:

```
\[
\langle \mu_{m} \rangle = 
\frac{{\displaystyle \sum_{-J}^{J}}{-g\mu_{\beta}M_{J}B.\exp{\left(\frac{-g\mu_{\beta}M_{J}B}{kT}\right)}}}
{{\displaystyle \sum_{-J}^{J}}{\exp{\left(\frac{-g\mu_{\beta}M_{J}B}{kT}\right)}}}
\]
```

PLEASE, use `\langle \rangle` instead of `< >`. Here's the output:
[image]

Comment: `\displaystyle` is not recommended here. See @Paul's comment above. The ideal would be `\sum\limits`.

Comment: Also, `\left` and `\right` add certain unwanted space, better `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`. And one more, if you want to use the `.` as a multiplication symbol (binary operator), wether you define a command, or use `\mathbin{.}`.

Comment: @Sigur Err... ok. Displaystyle also makes the sigma bigger, but maybe it looks better this way.

Comment: @JairoBochi I too would use `\sum\limits` *precisely* in order to avoid big summation signs; you might show both alternatives. The period is *never* used for multiplication in math, as far as I know. Either `\cdot` or nothing. In this case nothing is surely better.

Comment: ``LaTeX by default uses scriptstyle for sums inside fractions'' NO. **TeX** by defaults uses scriptstyle for sums inside fractions.

Comment: I think the best solution is to use the `nccmath` package, and `\medop`sum\limits_{-J}^{J}` to have `medium-sized` sum operator.

Comment: @wipet Your statement is more precise than mine, true, which doesn't mean that my statement is false (as you implied).

Comment: @JairoBochi It is much better to distinguish between TeX features and LaTeX features. LaTeX is only a macro package. LaTeX isn't all what we are doing with TeX. When you write: "LaTeX does something" then it seems that this feature is LaTeX specific and it is implemented by LaTeX macros. Many LaTeX manuals unfortunatelly don't distinguish this and it is bad practice.